# Concentration for stochastic integral involving the Brownian motion itself

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\{W_t\}_{0 \le t \le h}$ be Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}$. If $\{g_t\}_{0 \le t \le h} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a *fixed* scalar field (independent of the Brownian motion) parameterized by time, then I know how to obtain concentration of the following integral:
$$\int_0^h g_t dW_t$$
because it is equivalent via time-change to a draw from the distribution
$$\mathcal{N}\left(0, \int_0^h g_t^2 dt \right). $$
My question is what to do in the case when we are dealing with a scalar field that depends on the Brownian motion. In particular, suppose $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is some scalar field (say it is $1$-Lipschitz, so it can grow if the Brownian motion gets too large), and I want to understand concentration of
$$\int_0^h g(W_t)dW_t.$$
Is there a standard way of doing this? My apologies if this is a naive question.

Edit: I am trying to be competitive with the following strategy -- first, apply some tail bound on how large $W_t$ ever gets, and then using this tail bound obtain a bound on the variance in
$$\mathcal{N}\left(0, \int_0^h g(W_t)^2 dt\right). $$
Then, apply a standard Gaussian tail bound. However, I feel this doesn't make any sense since if I tell you the trajectory of the Brownian motion then the integral is no longer a random variable, so it doesn't seem right to treat the result as a draw from an appropriate Gaussian.

Comment: What do you mean by "concentration" ?

Comment: Like how well does that integral concentrate (i.e. some simple tail bounds). For the fixed scalar field it is simple to just evaluate the variance and apply standard Gaussian concentration, I'm wondering what to do in the more general case.

Answer (score 1):

## Answer for linear g

By definition for partitions $\pi=\{0=t_0<...<t_n=h\}$, $|\pi| = \sup_{i} |t_{i+1} - t_i |$

$$\int_0^h g(W_t)dW_t = \lim_{|\pi|\to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} g(W_{t_i})(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) $$

So for $g(x) = ax +b$ we can do the following:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (aW_{t_i} + b)(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) 
&= a \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} W_{t_i} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) + b\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) \\
&= a \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} W_{t_i} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) + b(W_h - W_0)
\end{align}$$

So we only really need $g(x) = x$, which we can get using the following argument:
$$x(y-x) = xy - x^2 =\frac{x^2 + y^2 -(x-y)^2}{2} - x^2 = \frac{1}{2}((y^2-x^2) -(y-x)^2)$$

Which means

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} W_{t_i} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) 
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}^2-W_{t_i}^2)}_{=W^2_h - W^2_0} + \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})^2}_{\to [W]_h-[W]_0 = h-0}\right)\\
&\to\frac{1}{2}(W_h^2 - h)
\end{align}$$

where $[W]_h=h$ is the [quadratic variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation) of the brownian motion. So for linear $g(x)=ax+b$, we get:

$$\int_0^h g(W_t)dW_t = \frac{a}{2}(W_h^2 - h) + bW_h$$

## Possible approach for non linear, differentiable g

By the Ito Formula

$$F(W_h) - F(W_0) = \int_0^h \underbrace{\frac{\partial  F}{\partial x}(W_t)}_{\stackrel{!}{=}g(W_t)} dW_t + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^h \underbrace{\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}(W_t)}_{=g'(W_t)} d[W]_t$$

So

$$\int_0^h g(W_t)dW_t = \int_0^{W_h}g(x)dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^h g'(W_t) dt$$

The issue here of course is the calculation of the integral over $g'$. If the derivative is bounded this might provide you with some bounds though.